# How to update WordPress plugins properly using git?

Tags: updates, git

I just updated some plugins (woocommerce, polylang) of a local copy of a running wordpress website. As I'm using `git` I wanted to commit the changes and sync with the live-host. But the problem is, that the updates also updated the database. Now I'm a bit confused, because if I sync now with `git` the database won't be updated on the live system as for example `woocommerce` asks me to trigger the database update once I have updated the plugin. On the other hand, I saw in other people's `.gitignore` file, that no one ignores `wp-content/plugins`. I could also dump the local database and insert into the live systems, but the data is too different.

My plan right now is to update on live first, make a `git commit` and sync with the local copy - if the local copy gets broken I'll pull in the database and a fresh copy from the live system. The big disadvantage here is, that for future updates your testing systems becomes the live-system, in other words, no testing before updates. You see I'm really confused about how to do that.

So my question is how to update WordPress plugins properly using `git`? How do you folks handle this?

Comment: are you tracking your database in `git`? How did a `git commit` change your database? Git only tracks files, I think there are significant gaps in your question with differences between what you're doing and what you've written driven by some assumptions nobody else is aware of. Try and assume we have no idea what you're talking about, and rid yourself of the idea there is a "standard" way of doing things that you tried to follow, and just explain your system in its entirety

Comment: The database is not in `git`. When I update a plugin on system `A`, the plugin will update the code and the database, but only the code will be in `git`. When I sync now with host `B` I will update the code using `git`, but not the database. And as the code has been synced with the most current version of the plugin I'm afraid, that the plugin will not try to update the database and I'll have a inconsistency.

Comment: Why would the plugin update the DB automatically on `A` but not on `B`? Are you doing something hacky that would mess with it? If there is an inconsistency why's that an issue? Just pull down the production data to your local, local environments regularly "desync". It sounds like what you needed to do was just do it and see what happens, but you wanted reassurance instead

Comment: Maybe because this process is triggered during update.

Comment: Well then, download the zip of the new updated plugin, and manually update it rather than using the built in updater, and find out that way. Suffice to say this is an issue I have never encountered or had to worry about

Comment: Do you put `wp-content/plugins` into your `.gitignore`? Because this would also be a solution and one could update the plugins on each host separately.

Comment: I do ignore WP core files and just click the button on each testing instance manually. Updates are quite safe these times and i did not need to roll back ever...

Comment: I've never put the plugins folder in gitignore, that would break plugins on a lot of hosts, e.g. WP Engine

Comment: I've posted an answer, but I suspect this is just looking for reassurance, and is actually a discussion opener, not a question. Keep in mind this is a Q&A site, not a discussion forum, you need to be able to mark an answer not just as what worked for you, but as canonically correct for all people

Comment: @TomJNowell - `I've never put the plugins folder in gitignore, that would break plugins on a lot of hosts, e.g. WP Engine` - why would that brake the plugins as this is code which could be downloaded and used "on the fly"? Could you please explain what you mean?

Comment: Because a lot of hosts don't have FTP, they use `git`, if you git ignore the plugins folder than there's no mechanism for adding plugins on these hosts, and no way to make changes to the `plugins` folder, and when you `git clone` the repo, there's no plugins folder thanks to you having no files in it

Answer (score 0):

No it's fine, lots of hosts depend on plugins being stored in git this way and it isn't an issue.

You can replicate the process by manually updating a file locally to test. Plugin authors tend to store a database version field, and update if it's mismatched, or they rely on functions such as `dbdelta` which auto-update table schema